# Program compiled with glibc can run on Linux with uClibc?

Tags: glibc, openwrt, uclibc

I have a program compiled using glibc and I need it runs on a MIPS target with Openwrt firmware using uClibc. Is this possible? I put the program in Openwrt and when I try to run it the result is: not found.

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

uClibc is only API-compatible, not ABI-compatible with glibc.

You should re-compile the application. To do so (at least until you know the details going on behind the scenes) I recommend to use the [openwrt buildroot](http://downloads.openwrt.org/docs/buildroot-documentation.html) (mostly because differences between the libraries lead to several incompatibilities). All you need is the [toolchain](http://downloads.openwrt.org/docs/buildroot-documentation.html#toolchain_standalone).

BTW, the documentation may be severely outdated, if you feel something is wrong, go with the uClibc buildroot [documentation](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/buildroot.html).

Answer (score 0):

More specificaly, the first place this will likely fail and cause the error you are seeing, is that the intepreter path specified in the executable (use readelf) does not exist